# libiconv.so: has text relocations

Tags: android, shared-libraries, android-6.0-marshmallow, unsatisfiedlinkerror

My app is targeted to run on android 6 which doesn't allow to load shared libraries as I understand.

Have anyone encountered this problem and was able to successfully solve it?

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/com.XXX.XXX-2/lib/arm/libiconv.so: has text relocations

Answer (score 10):

Android 6 no longer supports dynamic linking of shared objects. Static linking still works. However, your problem is unrelated to that.

The library is not even loaded because of its text relocations.

This is due to an old bug in the Android NDK, back in 2012. Google believed it to be solved with Lollipop, then ignored user warnings that it wasn't. The bug resurfaced in later NDKs, all API versions >=22 are considered broken. Instead of fixing the issue, apps with text relocations are now simply forbidden to deploy.

First report:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23203

To avoid the problem, try compiling your app with API 21. Refer to your IDE documentation on how to target various OS versions.